# Same project, same branch, two machines: unit tests producing inconsistent results

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, kotlin, junit

I'm really not sure what code to paste here. I'm including a link to my GitHub below, to the specific file with the error.

So all of a sudden a unit test that had previously been working fine started failing. It makes no sense whatsoever, the failure. I'm using Spring's MockMVC utility to simulate web API calls, and my tests with this tool mostly revolve around specific web logic, such as my security rules. The security rules are super important to me in these tests, I've got unit tests for all the access rules to all my APIs.

Anyway, this test, which should be testing a successfully authenticated request, is now returning a 401, which causes the test to fail. Looking at the code, I can't find anything wrong with it. I'm passing in a valid API token. However, I don't believe that any of my logic is to blame.

The reason I say that is because I did a test. Two computers, both on the develop branch of my project. I deleted my entire .m2 from both machines, did a clean compile, and then ran the tests. On one machine, all the tests pass. On the other machine, this one test fails.

This leads me to think one of two things is happening. Either something is seriously wrong on one of the machines, or it's a test order thing, meaning something is not being properly cleaned up between my tests.

This is reinforced by the fact that if I only run this one test file (mvn clean test -Dtest=VideoFileControllerTest), it works on both machines.

So... what could it be? I'm at a loss because I felt I was cleaning up everything properly between tests, I'm usually quite good at this. Advice and feedback would be appreciated.

https://github.com/craigmiller160/VideoManagerServer/blob/develop/src/test/kotlin/io/craigmiller160/videomanagerserver/controller/VideoFileControllerTest.kt

testAddVideoFile()

Answer (score 2):

I have checked out your project and ran the tests. Although I cannot pinpoint the exact cause of failure, it indeed looks like it has something to due with a form of test(data) contamination.

The tests started to fail after I randomized the order by modifying the maven surefire configuration. I added the following snippet in the build section of your `pom.xml` in order to randomize the tests:

```xml
<build>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <runOrder>random</runOrder>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
</build>
```

I ran the `mvn clean test` command ten times using the following (linux) bash script (if you use windows, the script might work using powershell):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
do
  mvn clean test
  if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]] ; then # if the exit code from mvn clean install was different than 0
    echo "Error during test ${i}" >> results.txt
  else
    echo "Test ${i} went fine" >> results.txt
  fi
done
```

Without the plugin snippet, the `results.txt` file merely contained ten lines of `Test x went fine`, while after applying the plugin about half of the tests failed. Unfortunately, the randomized tests all succeed when using `mvn clean test -Dtest=VideoFileControllerTest`, so my guess is that the contamination occurs somewhere else in your code.

I hope the above will give you more insight in the test failure. I would suggest searching for the culprit by `@Ignore`-ing halve of the active test classes and running the tests. If all tests succeed retry this process on the second halve and keep cutting the active tests in halve until you have found the cause of failure. Be sure to include to failing test though.

**[edit]**

You could add [`@DirtiesContext`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dirtiescontext) on the involved test classes/methods to prevent reuse of the `ApplicationContext` between tests.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, thanks for the advice, I figured it out.

So, the main purpose of my controller tests were to validate my API logic, including authentication. Which meant that there was logic that made static method calls to SecurityContextHolder. I had another test class that was also testing logic involving SecurityContextHolder, and it was doing this:

```
@Mock
    private lateinit var securityContext: SecurityContext

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext)
    }
```

So it was setting a Mockito mock object as the security context. After much investigation, I found that all my authentication logic was working fine on the test that was returning a 401 on my laptop (but not on my desktop). I also noticed that the test file with that code snippet above was running right before my controller test on my laptop, but after it on my desktop.

Furthermore, I had plenty of tests for an unauthenticated call, which is why only one test was failing: the unauthenticated test that followed it cleared the context.

The solution to this was to add the following logic to the test file from above:

```
@After
    fun after() {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
    }
```

This cleared the mock and got everything to work again.

Comment: Good to hear that you have found the issue, and thanks for sharing it!

Comment: Yeah well I hate finding SO posts that are incomplete haha. Appreciate the help.